# How to modify the reverse triangle properties in CSS

Tags: html, css

I m trying to modify a menu-bar template from http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/platinum-tabbed-dropdown-menu

the basic menu-bar structure as following `

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>`
```

For the tabs that include the second layer ,it consist of a reverse triangle ,like this ~~Food▼.

However , I want to make change of the triangle properties .What should I do ?

Comment: in this case, they use an embed svg in css. If you want to change it, just create a :hover state and modify the after attribute like : a:hover:after{ new triangle }

Answer (score 2):

This is called the ::after selector in CSS. The ::after selector inserts something after the content of each selected element(s). Use the content property to add the content what you need. S[image]ee the image below, that you are trying to follow below from chrome developer tools.

Comment: that means the triangle is a graphical photo ? How come I can't find the photo document from its template folder ? I should add `style:....`` behind its element to change its properties ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on developer console for the CSS code of one of the items with that triangle, you can see that it uses the :after CSS property and the triangle itself is an image:

[image]

So you can change it in your CSS adding another image or rotate with the CSS transform property as seen on the console.

Cheers!

Comment: that means the triangle is a graphical photo ? How come I can't find the photo document from its template folder ? I should add `style:....`` behind its element to change its properties ?

Comment: actually it's an image encoded in base64, so if you put all these base64 encoded characters in your browser navbar you're gonna see the image.